# Linkedin API fetch connection

Tags: php, json, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using simplelinkedin api to get profile and connection.

when i tried for get connection of current user i got the following error

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to connections denied",
  "requestId": "43V99BDZS8",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1424663614844
}
```

My API REQUEST IS

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=tokenvalue&format=json
```

But when i tried for profile data i got the result .. My request was like this

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,positions,headline,picture-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=tokenvalue&format=json
```

when i tried for get all connections it shows error.. is it something related to scope?

Comment: You tried with valid `tokenvalue` ?

Comment: yes , i have tried with valid token value , i hope thats why i got profile details. only when request for get connection shows that error

Comment: If you try with appropriate `tokenvalue` that you got in the developer console it should work. You have problem in that ??

Comment: Though it shows error `Unknown authentication scheme`

Comment: Hi i tried this url in console.. it shows error  same  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY&format=json

Comment: Yes `Access to connections denied` So the issue is in the api key and authentication.

Comment: But when i tried this with same api key i got the result https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,positions,headline,picture-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY&format=json

Comment: Simple, you are sending valid token in the previous url and not in the above url that you used :)

Comment: The difference is `/~/connections:(` between the first and second url

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY&format=json

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,positions,headline,picture-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY&format=json

Comment: please check this i have tried both has same token but one got result other one not

Comment: Yes that's the thing please check the url you can find that when you add this in url `~/connections:(` it shows the error

Comment: can you please clarify that.. and also can you put the correct url ?its urgent thats why ..

Comment: I understand, i will update it in my ansewr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to set the permission 
*private $SCOPE = array('r_fullprofile','r_emailaddress','rw_nus','r_network');*

like this way in simple linkedin library settings

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the request type

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,positions,headline,picture-url,email-address)

i.e., `~/connections`

Note : I didn't include the token that is beyond this url

More info [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/rest)

### Update :

As the questioner needs to get all the result

```
<?php
$RequestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,positions,headline,picture-url,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY&format=json";
$Result = file_get_contents($RequestUrl);
$Result = json_decode($Result);
print_r($Result);
?>
```

Comment: how can i correct this Sulthan.. ? when i refer tutorials the request is passing something like this.. my code is here

Comment: include('SimpleLinkedIn.php');
$obj = new SimpleLinkedIn('78xli1trmld8pl','lMkDcaJjEBg56tH6','http://localhost/test-linkedin/linkedin.php');
$res = $obj->authorize();
$resc = $obj->getTokenData();
if(!empty($resc)) {$obj->setTokenData('AQXcQRVtDQJePtXZzbUHhzl4kXydd0qxDly2PF3mIVOJGfjGAkVQKepiq8n6Rp0KOuUrFtmBmLH7JavKSA4-CejsCNXuXZMwEJRVIZ-dk8RoVe3AUYRQDSrlTEn9TyY_oIGeHiZVuP5uDPGWo0HX1J3YL_83s2o_2V_4pB1IKeOU_FN4xiY');
  $connection = $obj->fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url)');
  print_r($connection);

Comment: i want to get all connections of that user so i need to add ~/connections  in url i canot avoid this

Comment: I have updated the answer.. If you do `print_r($Result);` You shall get each data by getting inside the array of `$Result`

Comment: you didn't understand what i exactly means.. i got this url working fine earlier.. but i want  ~/connections of current user  Sulthan.the second url and first url results different datas..both are diferent request for different purpose. i want to make the second url working fine. first one is simply fetching profile data. second one is to fetch contacts or connections..

Comment: It is clear from the message that `Access to connections denied` The token didn't give access for this operation. Have you set all permission for this token ?

Comment: i have set default scope ... rw_company_admin,r_emailaddress,w_messages,rw_nus,rw_groups, r_fullprofile,r_network,r_contactinfo  .. is there any other permission settings?

Comment: I am not sure in which you are working .. You working here or what http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console ??

Comment: Ah, this is the third party website !! I recommend you to use http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console or related to the one which linkedin has as it own because while i test the request to get member profile i misbehaves. :(

Comment: finally i found the solution Sulthan.. we have to set the permission  private $SCOPE = array('r_fullprofile','r_emailaddress','rw_nus','r_network'); like this way..  thank you for spending this much time for me.

Comment: Ah, glad to help you @Anju as i can't able to see the permission scope i can't suggest you properly sorry for it :) If my answer helps you , you shall accept :)

Comment: i am using simplelinkedinapi , in this library we have to set scope..Actually when we create app we should specify default scope like above mentioned..and we can customize it via code.. its okay Sulthan, you spend lot of time for me thats enough..and definitely something from your suggestion direct me to check the permission..and thank you Sulthan..expect this support in future too.

Comment: You are welcome @Anju .. I never used linkedinapi , i used only googleapi and others  . Yeah for sure, you shall hit me at any time via stackovrflow or mail for any future support :)

Comment: Additionally if the solution was solved you shall click on the tick icon which is on the left side of my answer so that the question will be said as done :)